# Should replace on stack navigation replace the entire stack if I'm navigating to a screen in another stack?

Tags: react-native, mobile, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm creating a react native app which has nested navigation and I'm trying to figure out exactly what replace is doing.

Inside my App.tsx,

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name='Request-Center' component={RequestCenter} />
  <Stack.Screen name='Profile' component={Profile} />
<Stack.Navigator />
```

Inside Profile screen I have another stack navigator

```
<Stack.Navigator>

  <Stack.Screen name='Profile-Landing' component={ProfileLanding} />

  <Stack.Screen name='Deactivate-Account' component={DeactivateAccount} />

<Stack.Navigator />
```

And inside RequestCenter screen I have a stack navigator

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name='Request-Center-Landing' component={RequestCenterLanding} />
  <Stack.Screen name='Request-Center-Status' component={RequestCenterStatus} />
<Stack.Navigator />
```

Now I navigate to ProfileLanding screen inside Profile screen and then to DeactivateAccount screen which also exists inside Profile screen

Now when I navigate from DeactivateAccount screen to RequestCenterLanding screen inside RequestCenter screen/stack I use replace because when I go back I want to land on the ProfileLanding screen and not DeactivateAccount screen

What happens is that on back I find myself landing on Home page and not the ProfileLanding page

Which means, I believe, that the entire Profile stack constituting of ( ProfileLanding => DeactivateAccount ) gets wiped and not just the latter screen.

I hope I didn't overcomplicate it.
Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post how do you reset?